# How can I obtain the driver key for a driver programmatically?

Tags: wmi, wmic

I am attempting to programmatically determine the driver key. I know how to do it manually, which in my case is Device Manager > Display Adapters > *Name of display adapter* > Details > Select Driver Key under Property.

How can I do this programmatically? I can obtain Device class guid via wmic on commandline, but want to know how to get that extra bit of registry key information (for example, {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001 instead of just {4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}).