# How can I obtain the driver key for an installed device?

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Unfortunately this Question was asked 4 years ago but no answer yet [How can I obtain the driver key for a driver programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836592/how-can-i-obtain-the-driver-key-for-a-driver-programmatically)

actually if it was answered, I would not ask again.

I have a software depends on Naps2 scanner software.
I want to generate profiles.xml file and it depends on Driver Key and DeviceName

profiles.xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfScanProfile xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ScanProfile>
    <Device>
      <ID>{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0000</ID>
      <Name>HP Scanjet 300</Name>
    </Device>
    <DriverName>wia</DriverName>
    <DisplayName>HP Scanjet 300</DisplayName>
    <IconID>0</IconID>
    <MaxQuality>false</MaxQuality>
    <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <UseNativeUI>false</UseNativeUI>
    <AfterScanScale>OneToOne</AfterScanScale>
    <Brightness>0</Brightness>
    <Contrast>0</Contrast>
    <BitDepth>C24Bit</BitDepth>
    <PageAlign>Right</PageAlign>
    <PageSize>Letter</PageSize>
    <Resolution>Dpi200</Resolution>
    <PaperSource>Glass</PaperSource>
    <EnableAutoSave>false</EnableAutoSave>
    <Quality>75</Quality>
    <AutoDeskew>false</AutoDeskew>
    <BrightnessContrastAfterScan>false</BrightnessContrastAfterScan>
    <ForcePageSize>false</ForcePageSize>
    <ForcePageSizeCrop>false</ForcePageSizeCrop>
    <TwainImpl>Default</TwainImpl>
    <ExcludeBlankPages>false</ExcludeBlankPages>
    <BlankPageWhiteThreshold>70</BlankPageWhiteThreshold>
    <BlankPageCoverageThreshold>25</BlankPageCoverageThreshold>
    <WiaOffsetWidth>false</WiaOffsetWidth>
    <WiaRetryOnFailure>false</WiaRetryOnFailure>
    <WiaDelayBetweenScans>false</WiaDelayBetweenScans>
    <WiaDelayBetweenScansSeconds>2</WiaDelayBetweenScansSeconds>
    <WiaVersion>Default</WiaVersion>
    <FlipDuplexedPages>false</FlipDuplexedPages>
  </ScanProfile>
  <ScanProfile>
    <Device>
      <ID>HP Scanjet 300 TWAIN</ID>
      <Name>HP Scanjet 300 TWAIN</Name>
    </Device>
    <DriverName>twain</DriverName>
    <DisplayName>HP Scanjet 300 TWAIN</DisplayName>
    <IconID>0</IconID>
    <MaxQuality>false</MaxQuality>
    <IsDefault>false</IsDefault>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <UseNativeUI>false</UseNativeUI>
    <AfterScanScale>OneToOne</AfterScanScale>
    <Brightness>0</Brightness>
    <Contrast>0</Contrast>
    <BitDepth>C24Bit</BitDepth>
    <PageAlign>Right</PageAlign>
    <PageSize>Letter</PageSize>
    <Resolution>Dpi200</Resolution>
    <PaperSource>Glass</PaperSource>
    <EnableAutoSave>false</EnableAutoSave>
    <Quality>75</Quality>
    <AutoDeskew>false</AutoDeskew>
    <BrightnessContrastAfterScan>false</BrightnessContrastAfterScan>
    <ForcePageSize>false</ForcePageSize>
    <ForcePageSizeCrop>false</ForcePageSizeCrop>
    <TwainImpl>Default</TwainImpl>
    <ExcludeBlankPages>false</ExcludeBlankPages>
    <BlankPageWhiteThreshold>70</BlankPageWhiteThreshold>
    <BlankPageCoverageThreshold>25</BlankPageCoverageThreshold>
    <WiaOffsetWidth>false</WiaOffsetWidth>
    <WiaRetryOnFailure>false</WiaRetryOnFailure>
    <WiaDelayBetweenScans>false</WiaDelayBetweenScans>
    <WiaDelayBetweenScansSeconds>2</WiaDelayBetweenScansSeconds>
    <WiaVersion>Default</WiaVersion>
    <FlipDuplexedPages>false</FlipDuplexedPages>
  </ScanProfile>
</ArrayOfScanProfile>
```

after searching windows devices I found that the **Driver Key** {6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0000 is in here:

[image]

What I need is a PowerShell script or one-line script that gives me a Driver Key like **"{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0000"** with zeros or any number depending on how much scanners are connected to the machine
(**NOT Class GUID only {6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}**), and Device Name like below:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object { $_.PNPCLass -eq "Image"} | select *
```

Or

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | Where-Object { $_.PNPCLass -eq "Image" } | select *
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `Win32_PnPEntity` class.

Comment: already done but how to get Driver Key as per attached image

Comment: Why not just use PNPUtil.directly. `PNPUtil /help`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing all the stuff from my first response (if you kept that, it may be useful later to you) and coming back to what `Abraham Zinala` pointed you to and tweak it to get the value you are after.

```
# Using WMI
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity

Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"'

(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"')[1] | 
Select-Object -Property '*'

(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"')[1].GetDeviceProperties().DeviceProperties  | 
Select-Object -Property keyName, data | 
Select-Object -First 7
# Results
<#
keyName                      data                                        
-------                      ----                                        
DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc    Local Print Queue                           
DEVPKEY_Device_HardwareIds   {PRINTENUM\LocalPrintQueue}                 
DEVPKEY_Device_CompatibleIds {GenPrintQueue, SWD\GenericRaw, SWD\Generic}
DEVPKEY_Device_Class         PrintQueue                                  
DEVPKEY_Device_ClassGuid     {1ED2BBF9-...}      
DEVPKEY_Device_Driver        {1ed2bbf9-...}\0007 
DEVPKEY_Device_ConfigFlags   0                                           
...
#>


((Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"')[1].GetDeviceProperties().DeviceProperties).Data[7]
# Results
<#
{1ed2bbf9-...}\0007
#>


# Using CIM
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_pnpEntity

Get-CimInstance -ClassName  win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"'

(Get-CimInstance -ClassName  win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"')[1]

(Get-CimInstance -ClassName  win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"')[1] | 
Select-Object -Property '*'

# This however will fail
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName  win32_pnpEntity -Filter 'Name like "Brother%"')[1].GetDeviceProperties().DeviceProperties  | 
Select-Object -Property keyName, data | 
Select-Object -First 7
# Results
<#
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance] does not contain a method named 'GetDeviceProperties'
#>

# So, get the device Instance ID to pass to another cmdlet
(Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -ClassName Win32_PNPEntity | 
Where-Object PNPClass -like 'Print*')[2] | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
Status Class      FriendlyName   InstanceId                                          
------ -----      ------------   ----------                                          
OK     PrintQueue Brother...     SWD\PRINTENUM\...}

#>

($DeviceInstanceID = ((Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -ClassName Win32_PNPEntity | 
                    Where-Object PNPClass -like 'Print*')[2]).InstanceId)
# Results
<#
SWD\PRINTENUM\{0A235CEC-...}
#>
```

***Point of note:
Not all known cmdlets are available on all PS versions/OS platforms.***

I use my custom function to get such info dynamically as needed.

```
Get-CmdletVersion -CmdLetName Get-PnpDeviceProperty
# Results
<#
ModuleType Name      CmdletName_FinctionName PowerShellVersion
---------- ----      ----------------------- -----------------
                                                          
Manifest   PnpDevice Get-PnpDeviceProperty   5.1 
#>


Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId $DeviceInstanceID
# Results
<#
InstanceId KeyName                                   Type       Data                                                       
---------- -------                                   ----       ----                                                       
SWD\PRI... DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc                 String     Local Print Queue                                          
SWD\PRI... DEVPKEY_Device_HardwareIds                StringList {PRINTENUM\LocalPrintQueue}                                
SWD\PRI... DEVPKEY_Device_CompatibleIds              StringList {GenPrintQueue, SWD\GenericRaw, SWD\Generic}               
SWD\PRI... DEVPKEY_Device_Class                      String     PrintQueue                                                 
SWD\PRI... DEVPKEY_Device_ClassGuid                  Guid       {1ED2BBF9-...}                     
SWD\PRI... DEVPKEY_Device_Driver                     String     {1ed2bbf9-...}\0007                
...
#>

(Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId $DeviceInstanceID)[5].Data
# Results
<#
{1ed2bbf9-...}\0007
#>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still I cannot get "{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0000"
and what I get is only {6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F} without the last suffix \0000 or \0001 if there are two scanners connected to the machine

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my time!

Comment: Was a great help! Thanks [postanote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote)

Comment: @jacob-spitzer, glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're after is the Class GUID. You also tagged Posh 2/3/4.0 but, using `Get-CIMInstance` is the way to go: introduced in Powershell 3.0 - [Get-CIMInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=Get-Cim%20Instance%201%20Description.%20The%20Get-CimInstance%20cmdlet%20gets,CIM%20session%20to%20use%20for%20this%20cmdlet.) - gives you the same functionality of Get-WMIObject without as much security concerns.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -ClassName Win32_PNPEntity | Where-Object PNPClass -EQ "Image" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ClassGuid
```

Also, try to include the `-Namespace` parameter. It tends to query the objects faster even though the `Get-CIMInstance` cmdlet is pointed to the Root of the namespace; must be doing something under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still I cannot get "{6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F}\0000"
and what I get is only {6BDD1FC6-810F-11D0-BEC7-08002BE2092F} without the last suffix \0000 or \0001 if there are two scanners connected to the machine